# jest.fn() inside jest.mock() returns undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, testing, jestjs, create-react-app

I'm having a simple "util" module with a default export and 2 named exports.

```js
const foo = () => 'foo'
export default foo
    
export const bar = () => 'bar'
export const baz = () => 'baz'
```

on my test, I'm mocking it like that :

```js
jest.mock('./util', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: jest.fn(() => 'mocked foo'),
  bar: jest.fn(() => 'mocked bar'),
  baz: jest.fn(() => 'mocked baz'),
}))

describe('util', () => {
  //...
})
```

On my component, when I call `foo()`, `bar()` or `baz()`, I received `undefined`.
but everything is working if I remove `jest.fn()` like that :

```js
jest.mock('./util', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: () => 'mocked foo',
  bar: () => 'mocked bar',
  baz: () => 'mocked baz',
}))
```

My example is very close to the one on jest doc :
https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#mocking-partials

I'm using **React** (CRA) and **TypeScript**

I know there is different ways to mock a module but I'm curious to understand the issue that I'm facing.

any idea what I'm doing wrong ? :)
Thanks !

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I ran into the same issue (also running CRA) and found this might be the cause:

https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/9131#issuecomment-668790615

> A little late here, but I was just having this exact issue. I
> discovered that someone had added `resetMocks: true` to the
> `jest.config.js` file. This means that the implementations of mock
> functions are reset before each test. So in our case, the mock
> function was being included in the mocked module at test runtime, but
> that mock had been reset, so it returned undefined.
>
> Regarding the original issue build environment, it looks like
> react-scripts does indeed add `resetMocks: true` into the jest config.
> (https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/packages/react-scripts/scripts/utils/createJestConfig.js#L69)
> But you can override it on the jest key of your package.json.
> (https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/packages/react-scripts/scripts/utils/createJestConfig.js#L74)

Comment: I was aware of that change of setting in React17 but I never suspected that was my issue here. You are right, thanks a lot !