# Why does upgrading jest to 29.5.0 break my mocks?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, mocking, ts-jest

I'm upgrading jest in my project form 27.4.7 to 29.5.0 and suddenly my mocks for modules don't work. I've tried reading [the documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions) and it doesn't seem like anything changed, but it simply doesn't work. Maybe I missed something. All of the answers I can find here tell me to do the same thing I've always done, so I'm somewhat at a loss.

Here's an example:

mockTest.spec.ts

```
import { isTestPartnerId } from './utility';

jest.mock('./utility', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  isTestPartnerId: jest.fn(async (base, context, id) => Promise.resolve(id === 'testPartnerId'))
}));

describe('test mock', () => {

  it('should print true', async () => {
    console.log(await isTestPartnerId(null, null, 'testPartnerId'));
  });
});
```

It seems like this should print 'true' to the console, but instead I get 'undefined'. Debugging tests shows that `isTestPartnerId` is, in fact, undefined.

I am using typescript with ts-jest 29.0.5 (the latest).

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer. The clue was this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70270857/662970

In my case, we had `"restoreMocks": true` in the jest config in `package.json`. Removing that line has removed the issue.

Comment: The one thing I'm still not sure about is why it ever worked in the first place...

Comment: In nodejs app I am using jest 29.5.0 and getting `if (error?.stack) {...` error